# mysql search index different from one db to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql databases version 5.6.17 using InnoDB.    They are identical in structure.   One live, one dev. I have a search index on a table named news. I am searching for a 3 letter word like "tom".    The ft_min_word_len is set to 4 globally.

When I do a search using "tom" in one db the score comes back as 3.096 or higher on all the results.

when I do the same search in the other DB which is the same structure I get super small scores like .00000000000056565.

Why would the score be so different from one db to the other?  What should I be looking at?  This is an example of the query:

`select  *, match(info, title) against ('tom') as score from News where match(info,title) against ('tom')`

Thanks!

Comment: Could the faster database be caching the results? From the web page @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html: Searches for a single row in a single-row table are 238% faster with the query cache than without it. This can be regarded as close to the minimum speedup to be expected for a query that is cached.

Comment: So I think the issue might be the number of times it repeats.  In the dev side "tom" shows up in one record out of 75 and in the live side "tom" shows up in every record out of the 50 in the news table.  Is this why it is so low?  Because of the number of times it occurs across all records?